# CSS variables are not syntax-colored correctly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004505/how-to-use-kss-effectively-with-a-css-designed-for-dark-mode) and below, the variable names starting with `--something-` are not colored appropriately.

[image]

Comment: And `webkit-user-select`, `-moz-user-select`, `-ms-user-select`, `-webkit-appearance`, `-moz-appearance`, `-webkit-border-radius`, `-webkit-box-shadow`, `-webkit-padding-end`, `-webkit-padding-start`, `-webkit-user-select`? Or is that expected? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select).

Comment: Yeah, attributes with leading dashes don't seem to render quite right... If this is an issue with the actual highlighter, then this is better reported over on [the HLJS GitHub](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues).